# How to make listview scroll with SingleChildScrollView in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I put `ListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView` and listview inside `Wrap` so i want to make listview scroll with SingleChildScrollView
this is the `listView`

```dart
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0 ,right: 30.0 , left: 30.0),
  child: Center(
    child: Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child:ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return Align(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5,top: 0),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            items[index].img,
                            width: 60.0,
                            height: 60.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                                topRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Wrap(
                              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                              children:[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      items[index].name,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 25.0
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },),
```

Comment: I think you can use the slivers to do this with the CustomScrollView widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `physics` as `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` which will stop `ListView` Scrolling and will take `SingleChildScrollView` Scroll.

```
 ListView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: this is a *wrong* solution as it builds all the items for given `ListView` - for example if `itemCount` is 1000 then 1000 items will be build at once